# interfaceorientation in certain views only

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation, uidevice

I have a Main View that contatins uitableview, and I am pushing another view when the user taps on a row. I want only the child views to rotate and have written code for that. But the problem is once I push the view, it also enables the orientation on the Main View.

When I rotate the main view to the left, the statusbar also changes to the left. I have not applied any orientation on the Main View. I have done the following on the MainView but code still the status bar doesn't change.

```
 -(void) viewDidLoad
{
     [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(receivedRotate:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];
 }

-(void) receivedRotate: (NSNotification*) notification
 {
    UIDeviceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if(interfaceOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationUnknown)
    {
        if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        {
           [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
        }
    }

}
```

How can I disable interfaceOrientation in the Main view?

Answer (score 1):

in your main view controller, override this delegate:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation; // Override to allow rotation. Default returns YES only for UIDeviceOrientationPortrait
{
    if((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Now your main view controller will always be in landscape mode.
And remove all your code which you mentioned above.
you should not call the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:" method.

Comment: the shouldAutorotate function is not getting called automatically, so i have added a notification and called the function when the rotation notification is received. And i dnt want rotation in all the views, only in certain views. but it seems that my main view, where i have not applied rotation is affected by its child views. When i rotate the main view, everything stays in portrait except for statusbar. So any help on that????